# Pattern to define key/value properties by using a single String

Tags: javascript, properties, design-patterns

As you know, a single String can define many key/value properties. For instance, a query String can be defined as

```
someKey=someValue&anotherKey=anotherValue
```

Now **i need to define a pattern** in which a single String can define many key/value properties to be stored in a class attribute. **But** each value can be a String, an Array, A reference to a JavaScript function etc. Something like (Hypothetical pattern)

```
class="p=[1,2,3,4]&a=aaa&c=f()"
```

Its purpose: post-processing input Field through class atribute

Any advice to define a good pattern ?

Comment: Post-processing input Field through class attribute

Comment: @Arthur Ronald F D Garcia: So you want to abuse the `class` attribute?

Comment: @Gumbo Thank you for your reply. I do not want to abuse the class attribute. But because a runtime behavior, i need a way to store information about each input field. So a class attribute can be a good choice.

Comment: @Arthur Ronald F D Garcia: With HTML 5 you could use a `data-` prefixed attribute.

Comment: @Gumbo Good to know but, if possible, without HTML 5.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into Javascript Object Notation (JSON) at http://www.json.org/.

It describes basically what you are looking for, and is an industry standard way of packaging data nicely, so you won't be alone in using it.

**EDIT**: Given that the problem requires function references and/or runtime evaluation of functions, and that the whole thing is meant to be wrangled into a double quoted html class attribute, I second Gumbo's answer of just using javascript.

Comment: Good, But how can i define a good pattern to define a reference to a JavaScript function by using JSON ? Any advice ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to use plain JavaScript:

```
attr="p=[1,2,3,4];a='aaa';c=f"
```

Note that `c=f()` is not assigning the function *f* to *c* but the return value of the function *f*. `c=f` is assigning the function *f* to *c*.

You can evaluate that code with `eval`:

```
eval(element.getAttribute("attr"));
```

Comment: The term "reference" is misleading imo. The value of c is the function that is also the value of f. No need to de-reference it to get the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a string formatted as JSON:

```
var dataString = "'FirstName' : 'David', 'LastName' : 'Robbins', 'Dates' : {'BirthDate' : '12/12/1966', 'Graduated': '6/21/1984'}"
```

You can de-serialize the string to a Javascript object with the following call:

```
var userData = eval("(" + dataString +")");
```

You could natrually wrap the eval in another function.

Comment: Again: JSON does not know functions references nor functions.